# Django template with get_absolute_url() using args isn't working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

Having trouble using get_absolute_url() with args to work in my template (perhaps I'm doing this incorrectly on the template side)

I keep getting an error that says `person_id is not defined`

I've got a simple model that looks like this:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    year = models.ForeignKey(Year, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
```

It has `get_absolute_url` that looks like this:

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Return absolute url for Course."""
        return reverse(
            "view_course", args=[
                person_id, 
                location_id, 
                str(self.id)
            ]
        )
```

and I've got my URL which looks like this:

```
    path(
        "<person_id>/locations/<location_id>/course/<pk>/",
        views.CourseDetailView.as_view(),
        name="view_course",
    ),
```

In my template I've tried a few different ways to get this to display, currently it looks like this:

```
    {% for section in sections %}
        <a id="course{{section.course.id}}" href="{{person.id}}/locations/{{location.id}}/course/{{ section.course.get_absolute_url }}" class="card-link location-course-link">{{ location.person }}</a>{{section.course.short_name}}
    {% endfor %}
```

I have also tried: `href="{{ section.course.get_absolute_url }}"`

Also tried: `href="{{ section.course.get_absolute_url person.id location.id }}"`

While all the data is correct (the url comes out to `1/locations/3/course/5/` as expected in the template - it still gives that error when clicked on.

Comment: Hold on, where in your model do you store `person_id`?

Comment: I don't. person_id is the PK of the person whose data is being viewed. That person is tied to a location which is tied to a roster, which is tied to a section, which is tied to this course. There isn't a direct link between the two.

Comment: then you can not use the `get_absolute_url` here. A `get_absolute_url`, is supposed to be a link to a view that is *entirely* determined by that object.

Comment: Got it. That explains it then - I appreciate the help! If you want to put that in an answer, I'll mark it as good so others might know this in the event they run into it.

Comment: you can however use `{% url ... %}` here to make constructing the url more convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can not use `get_absolute_url` for that**. The [**`get_absolute_url`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) has as purpose:

> Define a `get_absolute_url()` method to tell Django how to calculate the **canonical URL for an object**. To callers, this method should appear to return a string that can be used to refer to the object over HTTP.

So that means the url is entirely determined by the object (through it fields, or through fields of related objects). But here there is, as far as I can see, no way to derive the `person_id`.

What you use the [**`{% url … }`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) to calculate the reverse url:

```
<a id="course{{section.course.id}}" href="{% url 'view_course' person.id location.id section.course.id %}" class="card-link location-course-link">{{ location.person }}</a>
```